# How to add a "Whats new or whats changed" feature to my intranet project?

Tags: asp.net

I work on our intranet, which is continuously being updated with new features or fixed bugs. Bugs and features are added to JIRA and then assigned to myself so that I can take care of those. Now I would like to add a new feature to the intranet, which shows the following information:

1. Current SVN version.
2. Current list of bug/fixes changes

What is the best way to achive both without hard-coding it into the website?

I am using ASP.NET.

I hope I explained everything. Please ask if anything is unclear.

Update 1:

I found the following link to solve #2: http://www.fatlemon.co.uk/2008/12/automatic-svn-revision-numbering-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JIRA can generate [Release Notes](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Release+Notes) pretty much automatically. As for the current SVN version, take a look at the footer of this site. In bottom right it reads "svn revision: 6181". Adding this is just a matter of properly configuring your CI server.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/use-svn-revision-to-label-build-in-ccnet) for info on how to label builds.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks I did not know that. Do you have any links which can create the svn revision links? I am using Cruise-Control.