# Turn off warning CS1607

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have a common assembly file where I have tried to turn off a warning:

> warning CS1607: Assembly generation -- The version '2.0.4.121106' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format

I have done this but it isn't working:

```
#pragma warning disable 1607    
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.4.121106")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("2.0.0.0")]
#pragma warning restore 1607
```

So is there some way to do this in the code?

Comment: This warning is there for a reason. Because at the OS-level each part of the version number can only be 16 bit, the OS will display a broken version number if you ignore this error. In your case the OS version number would be displayed as 2.0.4.55570.

Answer (score 13):

The reason why you are getting the error is because the revision number is greater than 65534. And I found researching the same problem for my solution is that there is no way (or easy/correct) to suppress this warning.  But in order for us to get around it we found that we could set the following code in out AssemblyVersion.cs with your versions as an example:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("2.0.4.121106")]
```

This will make it the Product Version of our dlls "2.0.4.121106" when viewing the details of the Properties > Details of our dlls.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it in project properties on "Build" tab. There is a field called "Suppress warnings" where you should put "1607" there.

Comment: Also, note that this will disable ALL other (probably valuable) CS1607 warnings too, not just the one with the version number.