# How to set version and build number from build server and also update an assembly with this version?

Tags: wix, continuous-integration

I would like to create a setup project based on WiX which does the following (as well as creating the installation package):

- callable from **msbuild** running on a CI build server (Hudson)
- take a version number from some asset in either the setup project or the main assembly
- take the current build number from the CI system
- create a full product version number [version].[build] such as 1.3.432
- store this value in an asset (e.g. the main assembly) is such a way that it can be read out at run time and displayed on the splash window

I have tried a number of approaches and googled a lot but have not found a workable solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can check my answer here:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/use-svn-revision-to-label-build-in-ccnet/12481921#12481921

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WiX toolset does this by creating a `version.cs`, a `version.h` and a `version.wxi` during the MSBuild then including those files in all the projects. That way our executable can print out their version when you run something like `candle.exe -?` and all of the bundles and .msi packages have their versions set correctly.

You can see how we do this in `tools\WixBuild.Version.targets` ([here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/tools/WixBuild.Version.targets)). It would straight forward to override the properties in `WixBuild.Version.targets` with properties passed via the command-line to MSBuild via Hudson if you wanted.

Comment: I believe this is the updated link for GitHub: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/tools/WixBuild.Version.targets