# Svnversion revision error

Tags: .net, svn, msbuild

I am trying to retrieve the svn revision number using MSBuild to be used on the Assemblyinfo.cs but the revision number is returning -1. The script is shown below and using slik subversion 1.8. I have turned the diagnostic for MSBuild and the svnversion does return -1. The strangest thing it work fine on a legacy project.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Paul

```
<Target Name="Version">
<XmlRead XPath="/Revolution/Major" XmlFileName="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Version.xml">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="Major" />
</XmlRead>
<XmlRead XPath="/Revolution/Minor" XmlFileName="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Version.xml">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="Minor" />
</XmlRead>
<SvnVersion LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" ToolPath="$(ProgramFiles)\SlikSvn-1.6.9\bin">
  <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
</SvnVersion>
<Message Text="Version: $(Major).$(Minor).$(Revision).0" />
<AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS" OutputFile="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" AssemblyTitle="ITL.Fuel.Client" AssemblyDescription="ITL.Fuel.Client" AssemblyCompany="Ingenitech (NZ) Limited" AssemblyProduct="ITL.Fuel.Client" AssemblyCopyright="Copyright © Ingenitech (NZ) Limited 2008" ComVisible="false" Guid="51ec449f-f5fa-4506-b89f-77b743f02988" AssemblyVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Revision).0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For `SlikSvn-1.6.9\bin` and Working Copy in 1.8 format and

> using slik subversion 1.8

I see at least two problems

- Does svnversion in SlikSvn-1.6.9\bin exist?
- Can svnversion 1.6 (if exist) read 1.8-format Working Copy? (hint - no, it can't)

Comment: SlikSvn-1.6.9\bin does exists in the program files directory. I have tried updating the subversion in our jenkins build server and try both 1.6.9 and 1.8 but still return -1 for this new project. I believe you are right with the Subversion version causing the issue. So does svnversion returns -1 if the client and server version does not match?

Comment: @user468662 - I can't recall exit codes, but no - client's and server's version may differ. Does your jenkins work with server-URL or (maybe?) with local Working Copy? Can you re-play jenkins actions in console by hand (I never used NSBuild)?

Answer (score 0):

I use this task.

```
<SvnVersion LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" ToolPath="$(SVNToolPath)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="MySubVersionRevision" />
</SvnVersion>
```

http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

and/or

https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks has the ( FileUpdate and SvnVersion ) tasks.

Full example here:

[Use SVN Revision to label build in CCNET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/use-svn-revision-to-label-build-in-ccnet/12481921#12481921)